# Overlapping sounds Actionscript 3/AIR

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, audio, air

I have a Play(Resume)/Pause button in Frame 1 (Home Page). However, when the user navigates the application and decides to go back in Home Page by pressing the home button, the sound overlaps. And when the user press the other buttons, it began to overlap endlessly. Thanks! This is an Actionscript 3 Flash Application to be deployed in Android device using Adobe AIR. Here is my code:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var played:Boolean = false;
var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("music.mp3");
var mySound:Sound = new Sound;

if(played== false){
            played= true;
mySound.load(soundFile);
var myChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;
myChannel = mySound.play(0,999);

pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseSound)
function pauseSound(event:MouseEvent):void 
    {
        var position = myChannel.position;
        myChannel.stop();
        play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,resumeSound);
        }

function resumeSound(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        myChannel = mySound.play(myChannel.position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not use initialization code in timeline. Also don't start a sound unless there is a valid `SoundChannel` in `myChannel`, this requires some more checks. Also `position` is function local in `pauseSound()`, move to global or else you'll lose data and won't be able to resume your sound.

Comment: @Vesper thank you! I am a beginner in Flash, please bear with me. Could you please give me your version of corrected code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's what you get by coding in frames rather than classes.

Solution A: make a class out of your frame 1 script so it is executed only once (when main timeline is created).

Solution B: make check before creating a duplicate:

```
var played:Boolean;

var mySound:Sound;
var myChannel:SoundChannel

// That will be executed only once, because the
// next time this variable will be initialized.
if (mySound == null)
{
    played = true;

    var soundFile:URLRequest = new URLRequest("music.mp3");

    mySound = new Sound;
    mySound.load(soundFile);
    myChannel = new SoundChannel;
    myChannel = mySound.play(0,999);

    pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pauseSound);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Organis! May I ask, Where would I put my resume capability of play_btn?

Comment: Just define that function in the first frame, only be sure to subscribe for it only once.

Comment: @niagrafallsxxx check [**this tutorial**](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/). See the sections titled `Stopping a sound` followed by `Pausing a sound`. Best to make separate functions for handling audio pause & resume. Use Boolean to toggle (true/false for pause/resume)...

Comment: @VC.One, thanks! I have tried to use the code (the code is in frame 1). When I am in Frame 2 and decides to go back in frame 1, the sound overlaps. What could be the possible solution for this?

Comment: @niagrafallsxxx look at my code above. It does exactly that.

Comment: @Organis hello! I am wondering, where's the instance name of the play button? thanks!

Comment: @niagrafallsxxx Erm... in your project? Click the button and on the properties panel you will see its name. Why?

Comment: @Organis i mean, where's the instance name of the play button (play_btn) in the code you've given me? I want my music to play using play button and pause using pause button. Thanks!

Comment: @Organis also if you may, maybe you know the answer in my question here. thanks again! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42263898/dynamic-txtfield-issue-in-different-frames-in-actionscript-3

Comment: @niagrafallsxxx I strongly advise to move this functionality, as frame independent, to an AS3 class. Thus you don't have to worry about code might get executed just because timeline playhead enters into frame.